# Problems with associated values of enums

Tags: swift, casting, swift2, anyobject

I have created a response *enum* for my network return value and a function which should return an `AnyObject` because it becomes it has to be a value of a key.

```
enum Response {

    case Success(value:AnyObject)
    case Failure(errorNumber: Int)

    func getResponse() -> AnyObject{
        switch self {
        case .Success(value: AnyObject):
            return value
        case .Failure(errorNumber: Int):
            return errorNumber
        }
    }

}
```

Generating the errors below:
[image]
<sub>I didn't add the actual text for the errors because I wanted to show you that it even doesn't do syntax highlighting for errorNumber and value</sub>

Eventually in my code I would have to assign this value to an `AnyObject` which later that anyobject will be downcasted to `[NSObject : AnyObject]`

So I would have:

```
var data : AnyObject? // <-- from our internal framework
data = Response.Success(data)
var params = data as! [NSObject : AnyObject] // <-- from our internal framework
```

The first code snippet is my new code, but the internal frameworks are lines of code I can't change.

FYI Our code is still using Swift2 :(

Comment: Your syntax is wrong, it should be `case .Success(let value):`

Comment: Eliminate the `getResponse()` function. Treat the enum for what it is, a data value or an error. Recombining these back into a single return value of type Any/AnyObject throws away information and causes typecasting hell later on.

Comment: Just because you're using `AnyObject` later, doesn't mean that `Response` should be dealing in it – I would recommend making it generic instead, e.g `Response<T>` with a `case Success(value: T)` (and as Price says, you shouldn't be combining the cases together – what if an `Int` is a valid success value?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you give the [Swift Book](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-ID145) a read:

```
func getResponse() -> Any {
    switch self {
    case .Success(let value):
        return value
    case .Failure(let errorNumber):
        return errorNumber
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've already *read* the book and other stuff. It's these problems that come when you're *applying* them :D. I'm using Swift2, doesn't that mean `Any` is out of scope.

Comment: @Honey If you still using Swift 2 you should use `AnyObject` otherwise use `Any`